# How do I add a drop-down list in Post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I add a drop-down list of all possible categories in Post's new page?

Here's the current set-up (it's very piecemeal due to cobbling together from various tutorials online). Please let me know if there's further information that I should have added. Thank you.

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :posts, :through => :cateogorizations
end
```

**Categorization Model**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :category
end
```

**Post _form.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
      <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**Categorization _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@categorization) do |f| %>
  <% if @categorization.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@categorization.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this categorization from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @categorization.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.select :post_id, Post.all.collect {|p| [p.title, p.id]} %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id ]} %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

I was able to make it show up in Post's form with this line:

`<%= collection_select(:post, :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } )%>`

Actually, mini-second update, I changed it to this line:

`<%= select("post", "category_ids", Category.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }) %>`

Cause I wanted a drop-down list per se, instead of a collection list.

Yay! How do I make it show up in Post's show page?