# How to make show category in Post's show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010915/how-do-i-add-a-drop-down-list-in-post) earlier, but it has changed since I was able to semi-solve it.

Realized it might be better to ask a new question instead of adding it to my earlier question.

How do I show the categories chosen in Post's show page?

**Post _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= select("post", "category_ids", Category.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :posts, :through => :cateogorizations
end
```

**Categorization Model**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :category
end
```

I am trying to add it to Post's show page so it shows up.

**Post's Show Page**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Body:</strong>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>



<ul>
    <%= render(partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @post.comments) %>
</ul>

<h3>Add Comments!</h3>

<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a comment" %><br />
<%= f.submit "Add Comment" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

<br/>
<%= link_to 'Posts Index', posts_path %>
```

I have tried doing this:

```
<p>
    <strong>Category:</strong>
    <%= @post.category.name %>
</p>
```

But all I get is `undefined method category' for #<Post:0x007fc239bad260>`

Advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= @post.categories.map(&:name) %>
```

Comment: @ Uzbekjon, just tried your answer right now. This is what I get: `Category: [] `

Comment: Does that specific `@post` has associated categories?

Comment: yup. Only did the later posts where I chose a category.

Comment: Make sure they are actually in the DB. What is the value of `@post.categories.size`?

Comment: From your results of Pavan's code, you don't have any categories associated with your post.

Comment: so, just adding the select drop-down list in post's `_form.html.erb` isn't going to associate the categories with the post, right? How do I do that? Or another separate question, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

If the post `has_many :categories`, you can't do a singular `@post.category`. You will have to either iterate over them to display them, or join them, as you will be working with an array.

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method category' for #Post:0x007fc239bad260

Your association of `post` with `category` is `has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations`, so calling `@post.category` won't work. Instead you need to call `@post.categories`. The below code should work

```
<p>
  <strong>Category:</strong>
</p>
<% @post.categories.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just tried your answer. It's so weird, but it doesn't even show up on the Post's show page at all. Only the first two items still show ie, ie, `title`, and `body`, but nothing else!

Comment: Add `=` in here: `<%= @post.cat`. PS. Pavan must have meant to take `p` and `strong` tags out of the loop.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 That means that particular post doesn't have categories associated with it.

Comment: @Uzbekjon Are you telling me to add `=` in `<% @post.categories.each do |c| %>`? If so that will print the query result in the view which is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem stemmed from the fact that I had not put `category_ids` in posts_controller's `post_params`. It was simple as that. The minute I put that in, the category showed up.